# Hhow to print the X value at GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN

Tags: gnuplot

I can print the minimum x,y using print GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN, GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN
How can I print the  X value at  GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can set or plot labels. Check `help label` and `help labels`.  Keep in mind the variable `GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN` and `GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN` are only set **after** plotting. So instead you could use `stats`, check `help stats`. Maybe with these hints you can already find the solution yourself. As soon as I find time, I'll try to make a minimal example, or somebody else will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question again, I guess using `stats` and setting a label is the easiest way.
Check `help stats` and `help label`. In order to see which values `stats` is calculating type `show var STATS` in the gnuplot console.

**Code:**

```
### label the coordinates of y-min value
reset session

# create some random test data
set samples 20
set table $Data
    plot '+' u (invnorm(rand(0))):(invnorm(rand(0))) w table
unset table

stats $Data u 1:2 nooutput
set label 1 at STATS_pos_min_y, STATS_min_y sprintf("(%.2f|%.2f)",STATS_pos_min_y, STATS_min_y) offset 1,0

unset key
set offset 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1

plot $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 lc "red"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Good solution to my problem, what version of Gnuplot are you using?

Comment: @wornomsf  The code above should work from gnuplot 5.0 on and probably can be modified to work with even earlier versions. Which version are you using?

Comment: @wornomsf if this answers your question do not forget to accept the answer by checking the checkmark next to the answer. You can upvote if you have >15 reputation.